# Operand type mismatch for jmp

Tags: assembly

I want to jump with jmp $+2, but when I try to do this I get an error operand type mismatch JMP, my code is like this, what's wrong?

```
// b.c

#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 2;
    if(a<b)
    {
        asm("jmp $+0x2;");
        printf("hh\n");
        printf("jump hh\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

b.c: Assembler messages:
b.c:11: Error: operand type mismatch for `jmp'
```

Comment: What is `jmp $+0x2` supposed to do?

Comment: What compiler / assembler / options?  The `jmp $+0x2` syntax may be correct for some assemblers but not others.  For instance, in gcc with the GNU assembler and its AT&T-style syntax, you would need to write `asm("jmp .+0x2")`; the current address is named `.` instead of `$` in that assembler.  (Now, expecting the code to actually do anything useful or meaningful is an entirely different question...)

Comment: Is this supposed to be a no-op jump (like if this was NASM syntax)?  AT&T doesn't support `$immediate` for jumps.

Comment: Yes! I've been looking for the compiler I use to write this instruction correctly, and jmp .+0x2 is just what I need. Thanks!